# visual artifacts, visible also on screenshots

Tags: graphics-card, visual-artifacts

For some time on my desktop computer I have strange visual artifacts. Here are a few examples of the artifacts:

[image]

[image]

[image]

These artifacts are visible even on screenshots (the pictures above are actual screenshots). They seem to be attached to windows of applications - when I move a window, artifacts move with it. Some programs seem to be more susceptibles to have artifacts - for instance, artifacts often appear in Firefox and Chrome, but they never appear in a text editor called "xed". When I restart a program which displays artifacts, the artifacts disappear.
I use Linux Mint on this computer.

What can cause such problem?